# Is it possible to have a video runing in background with i3lock?

Tags: video, archlinux, lockscreen, i3

I use i3lock as my lockscreen, I've coded a little script to obtain random background images on it, but now I want to have video as lockscreen so I want to know if there is a way to put a video in the i3lock's background and if it's possible how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, i3lock does not support video playback.

From the [i3lock documentation](https://i3wm.org/i3lock/) / manpage:

> After starting it, you will see a white screen (you can configure the color/an image)

You can specify an image with `-i path` and a color with `-c rrggbb`. If you want to display video on your locked screen, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279379/how-to-display-a-video-on-my-lock-screen-instead-of-a-wallpaper)  on the Unix/Linux site.